# Understanding JSON and Dropbox API pulls

Tags: json, dropbox

so I'm jumping in head first here and trying to learn something new... I have an Angular Function that will pull in all the contents of a folder using the Dropbox API and list it into a JSON file (and later display it on a webpage.)

what I want to do next is to get a share link for all those files using the create_shared_link_with_settings API and put them into a JSON file for all the files in the folder.

here's what I have for the first part. If you could help me out or point me in the right direction on the proper way to tackle this.

```
        var app = angular.module("content-review", []);

    app.controller("Content-folders-4K", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http({
                url: 'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder',
                method: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: ({
                    "path": "/MIG/Projects/Hippo content Watermark/HD/011_Blue"
                }),
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Bearer APIKEYTHATIMNOTSHARING",
                },
            })

            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.UHD = response.data.entries;
                $scope.json = angular.toJson(response.data, true);
                console.log($scope.json)

            });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a shared link for a file or folder in Dropbox, the /2/sharing/create_shared_link_with_settings endpoint you mentioned is the correct endpoint to use. You can find the documentation [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings). There's also an example of calling it in curl that you can translate for use with your own HTTPS client.

You specify which item you want the link for using the `path` parameter similar to how you did for the /2/files/list_folder call you showed. You can get the path value from the `path_lower` value for each "entry" in the /2/files/list_folder responses.

Note that if a shared link already exists for the item, you'll get a `shared_link_already_exists` error. The error will include the existing shared link only if the settings for the existing link match the settings you requested. Otherwise, you'll need to call [/2/sharing/list_shared_links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links) to get the existing link.

Either way, you can parse the result of the successful call to get the `SharedLinkMetadata.url` value for use in your app.